# Windows Server 2008R2 Domain Controllers - Failed test VerifyReferences

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, wsus

While running DCDIAG on our Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise Domain Controllers, I discovered the following error message on both DCs.

These domain controllers where migrated from a Windows server 2003 to a windows server 2008R2 and SYSVOL was successfully migrated from FRS to DFSR over a year ago.

```
Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C$           C:\                             Default share
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
ADMIN$       C:\Windows                      Remote Admin
NETLOGON     C:\Windows\SYSVOL_DFSR\sysvol\xxx.local\SCRIPTS
                                             Logon server share
SYSVOL       C:\Windows\SYSVOL_DFSR\sysvol   Logon server share
The command completed successfully.
```

Over two months ago a read-only Domain Controller was added but only now has this error message been discovered.

```
Virtual Domain Controller

 Starting test: VerifyReferences
    Some objects relating to the DC EDISON-DC0 have problems:
       [1] Problem: Missing Expected Value
        Base Object: CN=EDISON-DC0,OU=Domain_ControllersOU_(WSUS_Notify),OU=Domain Controllers,DC=xxx,DC=local
        Base Object Description: "DC Account Object"
        Value Object Attribute Name: frsComputerReferenceBL
        Value Object Description: "SYSVOL FRS Member Object"
        Recommended Action: See Knowledge Base Article: Q312862

    ......................... EDISON-DC0 failed test VerifyReferences

Physical Domain Controller

 Starting test: VerifyReferences
    Some objects relating to the DC BABBAGE have problems:
       [1] Problem: Missing Expected Value
        Base Object: CN=BABBAGE,OU=Domain_ControllersOU_(WSUS_Notify),OU=Domain Controllers,DC=xxx,DC=local
        Base Object Description: "DC Account Object"
        Value Object Attribute Name: frsComputerReferenceBL
        Value Object Description: "SYSVOL FRS Member Object"
        Recommended Action: See Knowledge Base Article: Q312862

    ......................... BABBAGE failed test VerifyReferences
```

Windows Server 2012 Standard Read-Only Domain Controller

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = xxx-RODC0
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: xxx\xxx-RODC0
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: xxx\xxx-RODC0
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test Replications
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... xxx-RODC0 passed test VerifyReferences

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : xxx
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... xxx passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... xxx passed test CrossRefValidation

Running enterprise tests on : xxx.local
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... xxx.local passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... xxx.local passed test Intersite
PS C:\Windows\system32>

The error message only shows up on the Windows Server 2008R2 Domain Controllers.

So I decided to remove BABBAGE and EDISON-DC0 from the Domain_ControllersOU_(WSUS_Notify) OU and place  them back in the Domain Controllers OU and rerun the DCDIAG command. This time there was no issue with failed test VerifyReferences on either BABBAGE or EDISON-DC0.

The issue seems to be related to using additional OUs inside of the Domain Controllers OU to configure WSUS for the Domain Controllers.

I had two OUs within the Domain Controllers OU

Domain_ControllersOU_(WSUS_Notify) - BABBAGE & EDISON-DC0
Domain_ControllersOU_(WSUS_Schedule) - RODC

Any thoughts on how to resolve this so that I can use two separate WSUS policies to to patch the DCs manually and the RODC by schedule @ 03:00 would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of saying you should of stated earlier...... Just edit your question so it *does* state it earlier, Makes the question easier to read.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: 1: The error is superficial and is not causing an actual problem.  2: The error is related to an FRS setting, and FRS is not in use any longer (already migrated).  3: The error seems to have been due to an unorthodox configuration, as it was resolved after moving the domain controller to the correct Organization Unit. TLDR: that seems to have been the fix.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug on 2008 R2 RODC's and the relevant hotfix [is found here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2401600).

Upon promotion, the RODC is unable to create a DFSR Settings object for its own Computer account (since it's read-only), and so it has to ask another DC to create it.

If the RODC subsequently tries to write an attribute value to the newly created object but (using serverless binding) connects to another writable DC that haven't yet replicated the newly created DFSR Settings object from the first writable DC, you end up with inconsistencies like missing backlinks.

Comment: I should have stated that the read-only domain controller is running Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition, so I am not certain that your response is accurate and I would sooner wait for the next software update that contains this hotfix rather than take a chance on installing it.

Comment: Even though I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, the hotfix says its not applicable when I tried to install it